# How to get single AssetEntity from given path using photo_manager

Tags: flutter, dart, photo-management

i am using `photo_manager` `package` for handling with galley media

the following method is for fetch media

first getting the available albums

```
final  albums = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(onlyAll: true, type:RequestType.common);
```

second fetch media from given album index

```
final media = await albums[0].getAssetListPaged( page: pageIntIncreaseMap[fedback]!, size:50,)
```

now using for/loop to get per file features

```
for (var asset in media ) {
// action
}
```

now my question what if i want to get single AssetEntity by given path without to go through the last methods ..

i found the following method in plugin doc

```
final AssetEntity? asset = await AssetEntity.fromId('430');
```

this is work fine but i need to get AssetEntity using the path and not id ..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you ever find a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the [github here](https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_photo_manager#from-id). It's recommended to do it as so:

```dart
// Save an existed image to an entity from it's path.
final AssetEntity? imageEntityWithPath = await PhotoManager.editor.saveImageWithPath(
  path, // Use the absolute path of your source file, it's more like a copy method.
  title: 'same_as_above.jpg',
);
```